# About Flutter MVVM Architecture with GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

I have the following structure:

- ReportPageview
- ReportController
- ReportService
  ....

My question is about the controller.
My code was too long, cause I have a lot of differents items inside of it.
So, my screen have the components separated already, but I was confusing how to do it with my controller.

What I Did:

I created anothers controllers to do the logic, example:

- ReportAgeController (that controller will do all the logic for the age part, like count the items by age range)
- ReportGenderController (that controller will do all the logic for the gender part, like count the items by gender)

So, inside my ReportController there is:

```
class ReportController extends GetxController { 
    late ReportService _reportService;

    late AgeController ageController; 
    late GenderController genderController;

    onInit(){ 
        _reportService = Get.find<ReportService>(); 
        ageController = ageController(); 
        genderController = genderController(reportService: _reportService); 
    }

    onReady(){ 
        _getItems(); 
        _generateReport();
    } 

    _getItems(){
        items = _reportservice.getItems();
    }

    List items = [];

    _generateReport() { 
        for (var item in items) {      
            ageController.setAgeRange(item);       
            genderController.setGenderRange(item);   
        } 
        update();
    }
    ... another logic here
}
```

In this case, I can call the filtered items like

```
Text("Male count ${controller.genderController.all.toString()}");
```

My question is: AgeController and GenderController are not a service, but I have no idea if I can call them a Controller too.

How can a call these classes and how could be my structure?

My actual strucuture after my changes is:

- ReportPageview.dart
- ReportController.dart
- ItemsController (folder)

  - AgeController.dart
  - GenderController.dart
- ReportService.dart

Comment: The video is good (I just gave it a watch), and I can echo some of the concerns he voices. I have also used GetX in production and know it can be great help. I think, unfortunately, there isn't a perfect answer to your question as it is somewhat down to style and your own preferences. I think your current structure is alright; if you want to change it, that also seems fine.

Comment: @JoesephSchmoe Thank you for the answer. I worked with mobx, bloc and now with GetX, I can't change the state management in production, haha, that's why sometimes I have doubts about the architecture.

Comment: I understand what you mean friend, haha. I just think it will ultimately come down to what works best for you in terms of keeping the repo free of spaghetti code. Goodluck!